# Javascript file not executing when using Wordpress child-theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've linked a custom javascript file in a Wordpress child theme using functions.php. The code doesn't execute when the page loads, however when I run the same code in the console it works. The script loads which can be seen in google inspector under the sources tab. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
function script_js() {
wp_enqueue_script('tradejs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','script_js', 2000);
```

Script doesn't execute when page loads however works when run directly in the console? Ive also tried other code snippets, same results though.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("input[type='search'").attr("placeholder", "Search CODE or Keyword");
});
```

Comment: Any errors showing in browser dev tools console? What do you see when you do `console.log($("input[type='search'").length)` inside that same `ready()`? If it is zero,  the element doesn't exist yet. There are different reasons it may not exist when your code runs

Comment: There are no errors length = 1. With or without both code snippets

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $("input[type='search'").length;
});
s.fn.init [document]
0: document
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)

Comment: Ok. Well we now know two things...the code is running and the element exists. It's possible some other code changes the placeholder after your code runs. Just as a test try putting it in a long `setTimeout()` of a few seconds

Comment: Cheers @charlietfl nice work around.